# using UIReferenceLibraryViewController in custom popover controller

Tags: ios, popover

I am using custom popover controller(`WYPopoverController`) for iPhone and showing `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` in it. The view does come perfectly but `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` has 'Done' button on its navigation bar and when I click on it, it does not respond. Though if I click outside the popover then popover disappears. I simply want to disappear popover when 'Done' button is pressed.

Please note, if I use `UIPopoverController` for iPad, then 'Done' button in `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` does respond. Not sure what am I missing in custom implementation.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem to me seems like part of a terrible design by Apple, where the reference library controller dismisses itself rather than providing a delegate method notifying you to dismiss it. First, open a bug report with Apple and post the bug report number so people can duplicate it.

In absence of better options, I would suggest replacing the controller's navigation item's bar button item with your own, where that button would notify you of the user's tap and you'd dismiss the controller properly. This is a partial solution, as the reference library controller is a complex case, where it maintains a navigation stack internally. You may have to dig in the view controller parent/child hierarchy to find all cases.

Consider changing your design in the meantime, presenting the view modally instead of a popover on phone/pod devices.

Comment: @Shas `UIPopoverController` is an Apple controller, and it is also expected on iPad. Take a look at the private methods: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIReferenceLibraryViewController.h Notice it implements `_setPopoverController:` - this means, Apple has hooks in there to support the popover controller.